# Gracefully handle amcharts that have no data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, amcharts, ammap

I want know if my dataProvider is empty. When amCharts draw default null. How can i handle it dynamically.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "theme": "none",
    "type": "serial",
    "dataProvider": data,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "title": "Income in millions, USD"
    }]
```

If data should empty. How could be handle it..

Comment: I don't understand what your demand is. What should happen when your data provider is empty or null?

Answer (score 7):

You have two real options here.

The first thing you can do is check for data before calling `AmCharts.makeChart()` and only execute that function if there is data. You will probably want to show some kind of message to the user in the event there isnt any data.

Your second option is to display a message on the chart itself. [Here is an example on the AmCharts website that can help achieve this.](http://www.amcharts.com/tips/gracefully-handle-charts-data/)

Comment: @GMStevents, do you have a link for amcharts version 4 for the same? I tried to find it, but got no success.

Comment: @TonyMontana, If you found the solution for amcharts version 4, could you please share?

Comment: @Ram, I tried the link provided by GMStevens but my scenario was different so I had to scrap the idea. But I think you can used the link provided by GMStevens.

Comment: @TonyMontana, I tried with the help of link provided by GMStevens, but getting error. Nor sure my code is correct. Let me add my code as my answer, can you please check it once?

Comment: @Ram it would be better if you create the new post with the error you are getting, so including me others as well can provide you the solution.

Comment: sure. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, I had this situation where my pie chart data was coming from an API call and it could have an empty array and I wanted to show something instead of nothing in amchart 4.

so i found this example on their site that helped me:

[pie chart placeholder in amchart 4](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/showing-placeholder-for-empty-pie-chart/)

basically what it does is that it shows a placeholder (an empty pie chart) when the chart data array is empty. It looks nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it with amcharts 4:

```
chart.events.on("beforevalidated", function (event) {
    // check if there's data
    if (event.target.data.length === 0) {
        chart.closeAllPopups();
        chart.modal.container = document.body;
        chart.openModal("<strong>No data found!</strong>");
    }
});
```