# How to draw bar chart with empty data using Amchart 4?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I want show empty/dummy bar chart when no data using amcharts version 4 as shown in below link using amcharts version 3.

[Example with amcharts version 3](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/gracefully-handle-charts-data/)

I have tried something like below, but getting error.

```
reChartData = am4core.create("exeChart", am4charts.XYChart);
var categoryAxis = reChartData.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "";
var  valueAxis = reChartData.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 100;
var dataPoint = {
  dummyValue: 0
};
reChartData.data = dataPoint;
var series = reChartData.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.categoryX = "";
```

**Error:**

```
Error: Data fields for series "id-98" are not properly defined.
at e.validateData (charts.js:20)
at t.update (core.js:19)
at core.js:19
```

@GMStevents and @TonyMontana, can you please share your thoughts as you already discussed on similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361767/gracefully-handle-amcharts-that-have-no-data/29541463?noredirect=1#comment113905250_29541463) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the error you get is because you are not defining your series dataFields. You need to specify the names of dataFields for your series. For example:

```
series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
```

Secondly, the `XYChart.data` [is an array](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychart/#data_property). You cannot assign an object.

Then to show a message on the chart when there is no data, create a container on the chart and add a label, like so:

```
if (!reChartData.data || reChartData.data.length === 0){
  const noDataMessagecontainer = reChartData.chartContainer.createChild(am4core.Container);
  noDataMessagecontainer.align = 'center';
  noDataMessagecontainer.isMeasured = false;
  noDataMessagecontainer.x = am4core.percent(50);
  noDataMessagecontainer.horizontalCenter = 'middle';
  noDataMessagecontainer.y = am4core.percent(50);
  noDataMessagecontainer.verticalCenter = 'middle';
  noDataMessagecontainer.layout = 'vertical';

  const messageLabel = noDataMessagecontainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
  messageLabel.text = 'There is no data to show on this chart.';
  messageLabel.textAlign = 'middle';
  messageLabel.maxWidth = 300;
  messageLabel.wrap = true;
}
```

[image]

[See sample here](https://codepen.io/frankfajardo/pen/NWrYbwM?editors=0010)